# MySQL problem retrieving correct data with two status fields and Datediff

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

This one is weird, and for some reason I can not find the solution.

My Mysql database has the following two fields that I work with for this MySQL statement:
1.ReviewTracked, which is a date field
2. Status, which can have the following two statuses - Pending or Escalated.

When a record is on either of the two statuses (Pending or Escalated) I want to know if the ReviewTracked date is older than 13 days from the current date.

My problem is that if I include both statuses in my query I get records that is younger than 13 days (remember I only need older than 13 days). If I do only one status at a time the result is correct. I therefore suppose something must be wrong with my MySQL query.

My MySQL statement that results in the wrong population being retrieved:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2
FROM IT
  INNER JOIN Clients ON IT.ClientCode = Clients.ClientCode
WHERE ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), IT.ReviewTracked))>13 and IT.Status = 'Pending'
   or IT.Status = 'Escalated';
```

If I exclude either "IT.Status = 'Escalated'" or "IT.Status = 'Pending'" the query works fine. Also, I am using VBA to connect to the MySQL database (which works fine).

Any assistance in getting the query to work correctly when using both statuses will be highly appreciated!

Regards
dwsteyl

I've tried various combinations of my query, but none worked. This is the first time asking for help on any forum. I did a search, but could not find a similar problem.

Comment: Instead of the or in your where clause, try IT.Status IN ('Pending', 'Escalated');

Comment: Thank you, IT.Status IN () worked perfectly. I appreciate the input!

Answer (score 0):

That's a logical precendence issue. `OR` has lower prescendence than `AND`, so this:

```
where
    ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), IT.ReviewTracked))>13 and IT.Status = 'Pending' 
    or IT.Status = 'Escalated'
```

Actually reads like:

```
where
    ABS(DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), IT.ReviewTracked))>13 
    and ( IT.Status = 'Pending' or IT.Status = 'Escalated')
```

This gives you all records whose review date is older than 13 days (regardless of their status), and all records with statuses pending or escalated (regardless of their review date): obviously this is not what you want.

You would need explicit parentheses around the `OR`ed conditions. Note also that we can rewrite the date arithmetics:

```
where
    ( IT.ReviewTracked < current_date - interval 13 day and status = 'Pending' )
    or IT.Status = 'Escalated'
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I got it to work with the rewritten arithmetics. I did find that IT.Status IN ('Pending', 'Escalated') as suggested by Tom Boyd is easier to use, so I'll run with that. Appreciate the help!